# Convert two or more Simple Arrays to Multidimensional Array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

Given that I have these arrays:

`$array1`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Title1
    [1] => Title2
    [2] => Title3
    [3] => Title4
...
```

`$array2`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
...
```

`$array3`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
...
```

I want to convert all the upper arrays into one Multidimensional Array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Title1
            [1] => A
            [2] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Title2
            [1] => B
            [2] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Title3
            [1] => C
            [2] => 3
        )
...
```

I have this code that does what I want but is excessive and inefficient:

```
$result1 = array();
foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $tmp = array($value);
    if (isset($array2[$key])) {
        $tmp[] = $array2[$key];
    }
    $result1[] = $tmp;
}

$result2 = array();
$i=0;
foreach($result1 as $value){
  $result2[$i] = $value;
  $result2[$i][] = $array3[$i];
  $i++;
}

print_r($result2);
```

In terms of efficiency, how can I improve my code? Can this be done all in one "*foreach*"? What about if I have ten or even more simple arrays? If this is the case, using my code I would have to copy down the second foreach and change the variables for each other array that comes after the first two arrays.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to loop through all arrays at once, e.g.

```
$result = array_map(function($v1, $v2, $v3){
    return [$v1, $v2, $v3];
}, $array1, $array2, $array3);
```

Or you can use [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php), so if you expand you only have to add the variables to the array and don't have to add the arguments in the anonymous function:

```
$result = call_user_func_array("array_map", [NULL, $array1, $array2, $array3]);
```

Comment: Wow @Rizier123 . Always on top with good answers. Works perfectly. Thanks!!

Comment: You too :) @Rizier123

Answer (score 4):

`array_map()` is the way to go but it's much easier:

```
$result = array_map(null, $array1, $array2, $array3);
```

Comment: I thought today you only post `evil()` answers?! :D

Comment: Sorry ;-) `eval('$result = array_map(null, $array1, $array2, $array3);');`